# Google test/mock with Qt signals

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to test a `QObject` based class with will `emit` signals asynchronously (actually from a background thread).

I saw a post here about doing this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/RTgynKPa6ew

Which linked to this source code:

http://www.etotheipiplusone.com/projects/qsignalmock/qsignalmock.cpp 
http://www.etotheipiplusone.com/projects/qsignalmock/qsignalmock.h

This seems to be what I want - however as the author mentions this is missing a timeout/synchronization step.

As the linked post is quite old I'd like to know is there a better/more modern way to handle this? I can't believe I am the only person who would like to verify that a class emits its signals with expected data within a *reasonable* time frame.

For example lets say we have an object which starts a thread, sleeps and then emits a signal:

```
class ASyncObj : public QObject
{
public:
   void begin(); // fires OnResult after ~10 seconds using QTimer or QThread for example
signals:
   void OnResult(bool wasError);
};

TEST_F(ASyncTest, DidSignalFire)
{
    ASyncObj testObj;
    testObj.begin();

    // How can I wait for a timeout and verify that OnResult was called with a value of false?
}
```

Edit:

In the end I used QSignalSpy but noticed it has an issue it detecting signals being emitted depending on if it was sync or async. So I came up with this:

```
class QSignalSpyEx : public QSignalSpy
{
public:
    QSignalSpyEx(const QObject* obj, const char* aSignal)
        : QSignalSpy(obj, aSignal)
    {

    }

    bool waitForSignal(int timeout = 5000000)
    {
        // if true then signal was emitted synchronously  
        bool result = count() > 0;
        if (!result)
        {
            // if false then wait for async emit 
            result = wait(timeout);
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

This makes my original example become:

```
TEST_F(ASyncTest, DidSignalFire)
{
    ASyncObj testObj;

    QSignalSpyEx spy(&testObj, SIGNAL(OnResult(bool)));

    testObj.begin();

    spy.waitForSignal(); // assert true
    spy.takeFirst().at(0).toBool(); // assert whatever you expected the result to be

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you do not use [QtTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qttestlib/qttest-index.html) (it is quite handy). Anyway this contains [QSignalSpy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qttestlib/qsignalspy.html#details) which allows to test signals.
You should call [wait(int)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qttestlib/qsignalspy.html#wait) method which starts event loop until signal arrives or until timeout occurs.

I'm pretty sure you can mix it with googletest.

Comment: Looks like this won't work because wait(int) has a race condition. If the signal is emitted before wait is called then it appears as if the signal is never emitted, is there a way around this issue?

Comment: There won't be a race condition! 1. you should create `QSignalSpy` BEFORE you start actual test (before calling begin) then call `wait` after you did call `begin`, 2. by default slots invoked by signals emitted from different thread are processed by event loop of destination thread.

Comment: I do and there is a race condition as it depends on if the signal was emitted async or synchronously. If sync then signal spy wait will think no signal was emitted, otherwise it will. I managed to create a wrapper to solve this though.

Comment: Would be nice if Qt would have a QSignalSpy::wait(millis, emitCount) for this situation (would return without wait if count is already emitCount)